# Simple AJAX example with Python not working

Tags: python, ajax

I am trying to implement a simple AJAX example, based on the demo shown on this page:
http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php

I have copied the HTML portion and named it ajax_demo.html. For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Ajax Example</title>
<script language="Javascript">
function xmlhttpPost(strURL) {
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
    // Mozilla/Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    // IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
        }
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring());
}

function getquerystring() {
    var form     = document.forms['f1'];
    var word = form.word.value;
    qstr = 'w=' + escape(word);  // NOTE: no '?' before querystring
    return qstr;
}

function updatepage(str){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="f1">
  <p>word: <input name="word" type="text">
  <input value="Go" type="button" onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost("/cgi-bin/simple-ajax-example.py")'></p>
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Not shown above is the full real path to my simple-ajax-example.py here:

`<input value="Go" type="button" onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost("/cgi-bin/simple-ajax-example.py")'>`

Both files are on my apache server. For example:

```
 http://myserver.com/ajax_demo.html
 http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/simple-ajax-example.py
```

My Python script does work when called directly and looks like this:

```
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
secret_word = form.getvalue('word')

print "Content-type: text/html"
print ""
print "<p>The secret word is", secret_word, "<p>"
```

Problem is, this simply doesn't work. In the ajax_demo.html text box, when I enter text and click Go, nothing seems to happen.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need open a server to serve `../cgi-bin/` directory :)

try this commend,

```
python -m simpleHTTPServer 8100
```

-----EDIT-----

```
secret_word = form.getvalue('word')
qstr = 'word=' + escape(word)
```

Your querystring key is misspelled.

Comment: I have both files on my apache server. For example:
http://myserver.com/ajax_demo.html

http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/simple-ajax-example.py

It is now working such that when I click the Go button I see "The secret word is None" under the text box. Now the question is why is my text not substituted for None? I wonder if I have to accept a query string rather than a post.

Comment: `secret_word = form.getvalue('word')
qstr = 'word=' + escape(word)`

your querystring key misspelled?

Comment: Bingo! I changed this line in the ajax_demo.html file and it now works! 
`qstr = 'w=' + escape(word)`
changed to
`qstr = 'word=' + escape(word)`
Can you restate this as the solution so that I can vote for it? Thanks!